# Cannot debug in VS Code by attaching to Chrome

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have default config in launch.json. The site runs on port 8080.

```json
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "chrome",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Chrome against localhost",
            "url": "http://localhost:8080",
            "webRoot": "${workspaceRoot}"
        },
        {
            "type": "chrome",
            "request": "attach",
            "name": "Attach to Chrome",
            "port": 9222,
            "webRoot": "${workspaceRoot}"
        }
    ]
}
```

[image]

However, when I click on the Debug button, I get this error:

> Cannot connect to the target: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:9222

[image]

**Question 1: Why does VS Code assign port 9222 when creating this json?**

What is so special about this port that MS decided to put it in this launch.json?

**Question 2: What do I need to change to make things work?**

The Launch debug always launches a new window.
I am asking **specifically about Attach debug option**, so that it will open in a new tab instead.

Comment: you can follow the answers below and do this without serving using a webserver.

1. open your chrome instance with --remote-debugging-port=9222, etc.
2. navigate to the index file in webroot, for example c:\myfiles\webproject\index.html
3. set the "url" in launch.json to match that path.
4. start debugging.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

1. You need to install Debugger for Chrome extension for this to work. Open extensions in VS Code and search for Debugger for Chrome
2. You need to run a web server on the URL specified in the first configuration (default to http://localhost:8080). I use `serve` npm package that I installed globally. From my app folder I run `serve -p 8080`
3. Select Launch Chrome against localhost option. It will launch the browser and you can set breakpoints in your code and the debugging should work.

Regarding the second configuration (Attach to Chrome). There's nothing special about the port. In order to attach to Chrome you need to run Chrome with remote debugging enabled on port specified in the config. For example `chrome.exe --remote-debugging-port=9222`. I personally never use this options. Just follow the three steps above and you should be fine.

Comment: Btw to install serve globally : `npm i serve -g` in a terminal

Comment: Debugger for Chrome  is deprecated now

Comment: What if the application is running on a remote server using Tomcat instead on nodejs server? How we can do remote debugging of JavaScript in this case?

Answer (score 92):

When using the configuration `url`, vscode will search for a tab with the EXACT url and attach to it if found.

Use the configuration `urlFilter`, which can have wildcards like *, to attach the debugger to any sub route in your url.

e.g. `"urlFilter": "http://localhost:4200/*"`

The complete exacts steps to take:

1. configure your launch.json file to looks something like this:

   ```json
    {
      "version": "0.2.0",
      "configurations": [
        {
          "type": "chrome",
          "request": "attach",
          "name": "Attach to Chrome",
          "port": 9222,
          "urlFilter": "http://localhost:4200/*",
          "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
        }
      ]
    }
   ```
2. Close all opened chrome instances (make sure that all of them are killed using task manager in windows).
3. Launch chrome with the following parameter: --remote-debugging-port=9222

   Make sure that the port in this parameter is the same as the one configured in 'port' property of the attache to chrome configuration in the launch.json file (like the example above)

   You can add this parameter in your chrome shortcut properties by:

   - Right click your shortcut file and select properties
   - Chain it to `Target` property, e.g.

     "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --remote-debugging-port=9222
4. Navigate to your site. In this example, http://localhost:4200
5. Run 'Start debugging' in VS Code.

Comment: Adding * in the URL fixed this for me. Thanks for the pointer.

Comment: This is the answer I have waited for a long time. Thanks. To me worked with url either.

Comment: Using `urlFilter` instead of `url` worked for me. Here is the docs on this topic https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-chrome-debug#other-optional-launch-config-fields

Comment: Thanks for "urlFilter"!

Comment: (make sure that all of them are killed using task manager in windows). worked for me

Comment: Thank you! Opening Chrome with --remote-debugging-port=9222 and adding urlFilter worked!!

Comment: Not working for me. Chrome says `DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:9222/devtools/browser/b5495c54-7c07-4bdf-8891-e69c37eb171a` and VSCode just hangs trying to connect.

Comment: Adding * in the URL fixed this for me. Thanks for the pointer.

Comment: You've saved me SO much trouble with the restofthefuckingowl documentation from google on this. Thank you!

Comment: I am upvoting because this was the only answer that mentioned to **close all existing Chrome session**. Otherwise, when I launched chrome debugger, it would say something like *opening in existing browser session*, but then wouldn't actually launch the debug mode. Once all sessions were closed, then the new session it created triggered the debugger, which was evident in the console that I used to launch chrome.exe.

Comment: What if the application is running on a remote server using Tomcat instead on nodejs server? How we can do remote debugging of JavaScript in this case?

Comment: This answers the question perfectly. However... I personally find it easier to just use a "launch" configuration (`"request": "launch"`), which then launches a Chrome Window for you with debugging enabled in the same way - could be worth a mention.

Answer (score 40):

**The Debugger for Chrome extension is deprecated. You do not need it anymore.**

I came across this question when looking for help using the "Attach to Chrome" configuration in VSCode. While the accepted answer did give me a few hints, I did have to do some more digging. Here are the steps that worked for me in case anyone else finds them useful:

1. <strike>Install the Debugger for Chrome extension in VSCode</strike> Skip this, it's not needed anymore
2. Serve your files with a web server of your choice
3. [Launch Chrome with remote debugging enabled](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-chrome-debug)
4. In this new Chrome window navigate to the url that your web server is hosting (http://localhost:8080 for example).
5. In VSCode, add a configuration to your `launch.json` file that looks like this:

   ```json
   "configurations": [
     {
       "type": "chrome",
       "request": "attach",
       "port": 9222,
       "name": "Attach Chrome",
       "url": "http://localhost:8080/",
       "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
     }
   ]
   ```
6. Press the play button in VSCode with the 'Attach to Chrome' option selected from the drop down.

The key thing needed in the configuration file is the `url` field. This needs to be the URL where your files are being hosted and this URL needs to be currently open in the Chrome window that you just launched with remote debugging enabled. If you enter everything else right except this field, VSCode will give you an error message that says which urls are available. Something like `Cannot connect to runtime process, timeout after 10000 ms - (reason: Can't find a valid target that matches: localhost:8080/. Available pages: ["http://localhost:8080",...`

For the sake of completeness, here's how you launch Chrome with remote debugging enabled ([from the Debugger for Chrome README](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-chrome-debug)):

Windows:

- Right click the Chrome shortcut, and select properties
- In the "target" field, append `--remote-debugging-port=9222`
- Or in a command prompt, execute `<path to chrome>/chrome.exe --remote-debugging-port=9222`

MacOS:

- In a terminal, execute `/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome --remote-debugging-port=9222`

Linux:

- In a terminal, launch `google-chrome --remote-debugging-port=9222`

Comment: Best answer. I should also add that the `"url"` field should be set to whatever your page address is when open. The debugger tries to find the **exact** match in your browser tab. I was working with vue.js and the default url `"http://localhost:8080/"` does not work, it should be `"http://localhost:8080/#/"`.

Comment: This isn't working for me, guessing because the website (browser address bar) uses a different port from the JS assets server, so it's a different url... Any clue how to do debugging if the JS and HTTP are served from different urls?

Comment: What if the application is running on a remote server using Tomcat instead on nodejs server? How we can do remote debugging of JavaScript in this case?

Answer (score 9):

A 2020 complement answer...

VS Code has a new debug that is not stable yet but works as default on Insiders version at the moment.

It opens automatically a new Chrome instance with debugging for attached with these settings:

```json
{
  "name": "Attach to Chrome",
  "port": 9222,
  "request": "attach",
  "type": "pwa-chrome",
  "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}/src"
 }
```

Like any attached, you can run the debug any time at this new window opened by VS Code.
Or you can run the Chrome as debug mode previously to avoid the VS Code to open a new debug window just like @quicklikerabbit answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/51392142/7050878 but this time without the need of the URL parameter.

Answer (score 7):

The following procedure is for React applications created by [create-react-app](https://create-react-app.dev/):

1. Click the **Extensions** button in the [Activity Bar](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_basic-layout) and install the [Debugger for Chrome](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=msjsdiag.debugger-for-chrome) extension if it's not already installed.
2. Open a new **Terminal** window. `cd` to the client folder if necessary and install [chrome-launcher](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-launcher#readme):

   ```
   npm install chrome-launcher
   ```
3. Switch to the **Debugger** panel in the [Side Bar](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_basic-layout).
4. Click the **Configuration** drop-down at the top of the Side Bar and choose **"Add Configuration..."** Alternatively, press the little gear icon at the top of the Side Bar to open `launch.json` and then press the big blue button labeled **"Add Configuration..."**
5. From the list of configuration templates, choose `Chrome: Attach`. The following configuration should be added to `launch.json`:

   ```json
   {
       "name": "Attach to Chrome",
       "port": 9222,
       "request": "attach",
       "type": "pwa-chrome",
       "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
   },
   ```

   There's no need to change anything in this configuration.
6. Add a new file named `.env` with the following content to the root folder of your project (or to the root of the client folder if it's a full-stack application):

   ```
   BROWSER=launchChrome.js
   ```
7. Add a new file named `launchChrome.js` to the same folder, with the following content:

   ```js
    const chromeLauncher = require('chrome-launcher');
    chromeLauncher.launch({
        startingUrl: process.argv[2],
        port: 9222,
    }).then(function (chrome) {
        console.info('Chrome remote debugging port:', chrome.port);
    });
   ```
8. Launch your React app from the Terminal window:

   ```
   npm start
   ```
9. After a few seconds, you should see the following text:

   ```
   Starting the development server...

   Chrome remote debugging port: 9222
   ```
10. At the top of the Side Panel, choose the configuration `Attach to Chrome` and press the green triangle.
11. You can now place breakpoints in your React code and the debugger will break when it hits them. You can even debug your server and your client simultaneously by adding a `Node.js: Launch Program` configuration to `launch.json`.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I will put my measly two cents in :) unfortunately or fortunately I had a similar problem and the above post pointed me in the right direction and I learned a little something along the way. Please see my notes below:

1) If you are on Linux, after starting vsCode run the following Linux command:

```
sudo lsof -i -P -n | grep LISTEN
```

this will allow you to see what ports are being used, in my case you can see code on 5500.
[image: sudo lsof -i -P -n | grep LISTEN]

2) Assuming you have some test html/js code and vsCode has a server and debugger installed then the following files need to be configured as such:

## code-workspace file:

```
/*
Workspace settings override user settings.
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings
Check to see if needed ports are listening: sudo lsof -i -P -n | grep LISTEN
*/

{
    "folders": [
        {
            "path": "."
        }
    ],
    "settings": {
        "liveServer.settings.AdvanceCustomBrowserCmdLine": "google-chrome-stable --remote-debugging-port=9222",
    }
}
```

## launch.json:

```
{
/*
Workspace settings override user settings.
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings
Check to see if needed ports are listening: sudo lsof -i -P -n | grep LISTEN
*/
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Launch 127.0.0.1:5500",
            "type": "chrome",
            "request": "launch",
            "url": "http://127.0.0.1:5500/${relativeFileDirname}/${fileBasename}",
            "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}/${relativeFileDirname}"
        },
        {
            "name": "Attach 127.0.0.1:5500",
            "type": "chrome",
            "request": "attach",
            "port": 9222,
            "url": "http://127.0.0.1:5500/${relativeFileDirname}/${fileBasename}",
            "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}/${relativeFileDirname}/"
        },
    ]
  }
```

## setting.json:

```
/*
Workspace settings override user settings.
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings
Check to see if needed ports are listening: sudo lsof -i -P -n | grep LISTEN
    */

    {
        "cSpell.language": "en",
        "git.enableSmartCommit": true,
        "git.autofetch": true,
        "[html]": {
            "editor.defaultFormatter": "vscode.html-language-features"
        },
        "liveServer.settings.donotShowInfoMsg": true,
        "cSpell.userWords": [
            "lsof",
            "readonly"
        ],
        "[javascript]": {
            "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
        },
        "cSpell.enabledLanguageIds": [
            "asciidoc",
            "c",
            "cpp",
            "csharp",
            "css",
            "git-commit",
            "go",
            "handlebars",
            "haskell",
            "html",
            "jade",
            "java",
            "javascript",
            "javascriptreact",
            "json",
            "jsonc",
            "latex",
            "less",
            "markdown",
            "php",
            "plaintext",
            "pug",
            "python",
            "restructuredtext",
            "rust",
            "scala",
            "scss",
            "text",
            "typescript",
            "typescriptreact",
            "yaml",
            "yml"
        ],
    }
```

3) **NOTE make sure all browsers are closed before starting up the 'Live Server'.** Spin-up your server 'Live Server'to open the file you would like to debug as per the configuration for the chrome browser stipulated in the vsCode File>Preferences>Settings, **NOTE use 127.0.0.1 I had no luck with localhost**, also the default port is 5500. The browser is now launched as per the vsCode-workspace file setting *"liveServer.settings.AdvanceCustomBrowserCmdLine": "google-chrome-stable --remote-debugging-port=9222",* this is where the debug magic takes place. **NOTE make sure all browsers are closed before starting up the 'Live Server'.**
Especially check to make sure there are no chrome extension like Hangouts running, this will also prevent Chrome from opening port 9222, **I had to click the Exit option on the task to kill all Chrome extension** in my example:
[image]

4) Now if you run `sudo lsof -i -P -n | grep LISTEN` you will see vsCode 'Live Server' serving on port 127.0.0.1:5500 and the debugger doing its thing on port 127.0.0.1:9222; *If you do not see both ports opened then something is not correct and you will need to confirm STEP 3) listed above.*
[image: serving on port 5500 and the debugger doing its thing on port 9222]

5) You can check the web interface for the debugger by entering `http://127.0.0.1:9222/` in a empty browser tab, this url will display links to every tab and extensions open and allow you to poke around with the debugger, click on the link to the file you want to debug, in my case *127.0.0.1:5500/Leason_66/index.html*, this is the port and link vsCode will communicate with and re-render in the IDE Debugger.

[image: http://127.0.0.1:9222/]
[image: 127.0.0.1:5500/Leason_66/index.html]

6) **Note: Make sure you are on the file you want to debug.** We are almost there, now just click on the Debug Icon then go to the GREEN Play Button and select the attach option from the drop down, please note the information configured in the launch.js file is what will appear in the drop down.

[image: Time for some action!]

7) Time for some action! Now all you have to do is click on the GREEN Play Button and the Debugger will now attach to tab you have open at 127.0.0.1:5500/<*path you your file>* and do its debug on port 127.0.0.1:9222
[image]

8) Happy Engineering :)

Answer (score 1):

For me, the problem was actually the host my angular application was pointing to. In particular, the command `ng serve` was serving it on localhost by default, but the vs code remote debugger tries to connect to 127.0.0.1 and gets `ECONNREFUSED` because the app was being served on localhost.

Apparently there is a difference, even if your hosts file has `127.0.0.1 localhost` in it.

The solution was to serve the angular application on 127.0.0.1

`ng serve --host 127.0.0.1`

Answer (score 0):

Peek into Task Manager. You may have Chrome instances hanging there. Only after killing them will you be able to run the remote and successfully start the debugger.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```json
"type": "edge",
"request": "launch",
"name": "Launch Edge",
"url": "http://localhost:8080",
"webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
"file": "${workspaceFolder}/index.html"
```

Answer (score -1):

Run Chrome on macOS without command lines.

We'll create a shortcut of Chrome that will run `--remote-debugging-port=9222` for us.

### Steps

1. Open the native application called **Automator**.
2. It opens a selector. Our goal is to create an application, hence we choose **Application**.
   [image]
3. Look for `shell`.
   [image]
4. Add the next script `/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome --remote-debugging-port=9222`
   [image]
5. Then save it with your desire. Our application shortcut is done.
   [image]
6. Run the Spotlight with `CMD + Space` and type your app name, mine starts with `Chrome Debug`. Open it and *voilà*
7. Add the `launch.json` this configuration (you can edit the localhost's port):

```
{
      "name": "Chrome lh:4200",
      "type": "chrome",
      "request": "attach",
      "urlFilter": "http://localhost:4200/*",
      "port": 9222,
      "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
}
```

8. Run that debug configuration. VSCode is waiting. Open your localhost URL on the Chrome, VSCode debugger will show this state:
   [image]

Answer (score -1):

**Linux** users should have Chrome **deb** file installed from Google official website for it to work out of the box. Flat/Snap doesn't work unless with some more settings!

Comment: Not really.  `echo "#!/bin/bash\nchromium --remote-debugging-port=9222" > chrome`
, `chmod +x chrome`, `./chrome`

Comment: Thanks John. Does you solution resolve the Snap/Flatpak sandboxing?

Comment: I don't know what you're referring to, but I'm using the snap version of chromium if that matters.

Answer (score -1):

For chrome browser VSCode has intergrated debugger in the core installation.

Refer the vscode-js-debug extension to get started.