# Error trying to debug in VSCode with "Attach to Chrome" option using Debugger For Chrome plugin

Tags: google-chrome, debugging, typescript, visual-studio-code

Visual Studio Code.
Typescript files are compiled to JavaScript files with sourcemaps.
Generated launch.json:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "chrome",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Chrome against localhost",
            "url": "http://localhost:8080",
            "webRoot": "${workspaceRoot}"
        },
        {
            "type": "chrome",
            "request": "attach",
            "name": "Attach to Chrome",
            "port": 9222,
            "webRoot": "${workspaceRoot}"
        }
    ]
}
```

Chrome is started with parameter: --remote-debugging-port=9222

[image]

However I still get

**Cannot connect to the target: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:9222**

error in VSCode, when trying to debug with "Attach to Chrome" option.

[image]

Comment: The readme includes  a whole section on this error: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-chrome-debug#cannot-connect-to-the-target-connect-econnrefused-1270019222. However, I strongly recommend using the 'launch' config - it's much easier!

Comment: Its not easier when you are building apps to work with Google API, it will open a new Chrome window and will ask for Google account authentication and authorization (email & password) every time you run it. This doesn't happen when it opens it in a new tab.

Comment: Hm, I would think it would persist after you've logged in once. Maybe not.

Comment: this is a great tutorial http://kynatro.com/blog/2018/01/11/chrome-debugging-in-vscode/
make sure no other chrome instances or working and also that you are on the exact url as you state in the url field (and it's open in the browser)

Answer (score 1):

Using 'urlFIlter' with * as wildcard will fix your problem.

See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53319718/2342414) for more details.

Comment: This did not work for me. Getting the error, could not find any debuggable target a tlocalhost:3000 . < my app is running at port 3000>

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to achieve the same and tried the same without success but i found a different way.
Assuming you want to have the same browser session of your default one you can modify your `launch.json` to:

```
 {
  "configurations": [
    {
      "type": "chrome",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "Launch Chrome against localhost",
      "url": "http://localhost:5173",
      "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
      "userDataDir": false // <--
    }
  ]
}
```

You will get a new Chrome window but using your default Chrome profile (with all the extensions, bookmarks, etc..) with the debugging capabilities you were looking for.