# How to debug a nodemon project in VSCode

Tags: node.js, debugging, visual-studio-code, nodemon, vscode-debugger

I have a NodeJs project and I run it using nodemon,
I wish to run it in debug mode for development tasks, but I am unable to do so.

I found that I'll need to add the right configuration to the launch.json file under .vscode folder,
I have a `app.js` file which is the main app file.
And the application runs on `node version 4.6.2` and on `Port 8080`.
In usual case I run the App using `npm run dev` command.

**Following is my launch.json file -**

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "MyApp",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/app.js",
            "runtimeVersion": "4.6.2",
            "protocol": "legacy",
            "port": 8080
            //"runtimeExecutable": "/home/user/.nvm/versions/node/v4.6.2/bin/node"
        },
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "nodemon",
            "runtimeExecutable": "nodemon",
            "program": "${workspaceRoot}/app.js",
            "restart": true,
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "internalConsoleOptions": "neverOpen",
            "runtimeVersion": "4.6.2",
            "protocol": "legacy",
            "port": 8080
        },
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "DEBUG",
            "runtimeExecutable": "nodemon",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/app.js",
            "restart": true,
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "internalConsoleOptions": "neverOpen",
            "runtimeVersion": "4.6.2",
            "protocol": "legacy",
            "port": 8080
        }
    ]
}
```

**The package.json is as follows -**

```
{
  "name": "myapp",
  "description": "myapp",
  "version": "1.35.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "nodemon app.js",
    "debug": "nodemon app.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "async": "1.3.0",
    "aws-sdk": "2.7.20",
    "aws-xray-sdk": "^2.1.0",
    "aws-xray-sdk-restify": "^1.3.0-beta",
    "bcrypt": "0.8.5",
    "body-parser": "1.12.3",
    "compression": "^1.7.0",
    "connect-flash": "0.1.1",
    "cookie-parser": "1.3.4",
    "cron": "1.0.9",
    "csurf": "^1.9.0",
    "csvtojson": "^1.1.2",
    "date-utils": "1.2.16",
    "dotenv": "4.0.0",
    "email-templates": "1.2.1",
    "express": "4.12.3",
    "express-handlebars": "2.0.0",
    "express-jwt": "^5.1.0",
    "express-mailer": "0.2.4",
    "express-session": "1.11.1",
    "express-validator": "3.1.3",
    "handlebars": "^3.0.3",
    "helmet": "^3.5.0",
    "html-pdf": "1.4.0",
    "json-2-csv": "2.0.12",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^7.3.0",
    "multer": "^0.1.8",
    "mysql": "2.6.2",
    "newrelic": "1.25.0",
    "node-schedule": "^1.3.0",
    "nodemailer": "^1.3.4",
    "nodemailer-ses-transport": "1.2.0",
    "passport": "0.2.1",
    "passport-local": "1.0.0",
    "path": "0.11.14",
    "promise": "7.0.0",
    "qs": "^2.4.1",
    "replaceall": "0.1.6",
    "request": "2.55.0",
    "run-parallel": "1.1.0",
    "validator": "^7.0.0",
    "winston": "^2.3.1",
    "winston-daily-rotate-file": "^1.7.0",
    "xlsx": "0.8.8"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^1.17.3"
  }
}
```

**The App gets launched when I run the DEBUG and nodemon configurations,

But the code is not getting paused on the breakpoints I put on the app.js file.**

**Reference links -**
1. https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-recipes/tree/master/nodemon
2. https://github.com/bdspen/nodemon_vscode
3. [Can Visual Studio Code be configured to launch with nodemon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34450175/can-visual-studio-code-be-configured-to-launch-with-nodemon)
4. [Cannot debug in VSCode by attaching to Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45592581/cannot-debug-in-vscode-by-attaching-to-chrome?rq=1)
5. https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging

What changes are required in package.json, or any corrections in Launch configuration - launch.json, that would help me to debug the application in VSCode for my usecase?

Answer (score 74):

Change package.json to

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "node app.js",
    "debug": "nodemon --inspect app.js"
}
```

> --inspect is for versions >= 6.3. --legacy or --auto [for older versions](https://vscode.readthedocs.io/en/latest/nodejs/nodejs-debugging/)

And launch.json to:

```
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "type": "node",
        "request": "attach",
        "name": "Node: Nodemon",
        "processId": "${command:PickProcess}",
        "restart": true,
        "protocol": "inspector"
    }
]
```

the restart flag is the key here.

Start app via new debug script

> npm run debug

- In Debug view, select the **Node: Nodemon** configuration and press play
  or F5
- Choose the process started above

See more: [vscode nodemon recipe](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-recipes/tree/master/nodemon)

Comment: `--inspect is for versions >= 6.3. --legacy or --auto for older versions` refers to `node`, current is `v15`.

Comment: Note: the process you should choose is NOT the nodemon one but the node process which is running your app.

Answer (score 24):

In vscode config, you can set the `runtimeExecutable` which will run the program you give. set `restart:true` so vs code debugger can restart the process.

This is an example config:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "node", 
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "nodemon",
            "runtimeExecutable": "nodemon",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/bin/www",
            "restart": true,
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "internalConsoleOptions": "neverOpen",
            "env": {
                "debug": "app:*",
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Update `program` to the node file you want to debug.

It's easy than attaching a debugger to the running node process.

Comment: I know we shouldn't write comments just to say "thanks", but THANK YOU SO MUCH. I don't know how many different launch.json's I've tried without success until this one! (though, I had to change `"${workspaceFolder}/bin/www"` for `"${workspaceFolder}/server"` in my case).

Comment: I learned that when I use `launch` as in your example I need the `program` key related to my debug html file (but your `program` refers to a folder, not file). If I use `attach` as in the other example by Geek, I need the `processId` and `pick the process` I want to debug (which I started before with nodemon).

Answer (score 13):

I ran into a similar issue attaching to a Dockerized nodemon process. I found the solution in [this article](https://dev.to/alex_barashkov/how-to-debug-nodejs-in-a-docker-container-bhi). I was able to get it working by changing three things:

1. Added `--inspect=0.0.0.0` to the npm script that launched the service (named `debug` in my case):

```
  "scripts": {
    "debug": "nodemon -w lib -w server.js --inspect=0.0.0.0 server.js"
  }
```

2. Making sure port 9229 (or whatever debug port you wish to use) is open in the Docker container. I'm using `docker-compose`, so it's defined in the associated yaml:

```
ports:
  - "8080:8080"
  - "9229:9229"
```

3. Adding the following configuration to `launch.json` in VS Code:

```
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Attach to Node in Docker",
            "type": "node",
            "address": "localhost",
            "port": 9229,
            "request": "attach",
            "restart": true
        }
    ]
```

The `"restart": true` option allows the debugger to automatically reattach when nodemon recompiles things after a watched file changes.

Answer (score 10):

In 2022 i use this:

```
// launch.json
"configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Launch via NPM",
            "request": "launch",
            "runtimeArgs": ["run", "debug"],
            "runtimeExecutable": "npm",
            "skipFiles": ["<node_internals>/**"],
            "type": "node"
        }
    ]
```

```
// package.json
"scripts": {
        "debug": "nodemon dist/app"
    }
```

After this I click `Run and Debug: Launch via NPM` in vscode. And the debugger starts with nodemon and the breakpoints working when code changes.

Comment: do you have nodemon:{} configuration in package.json ?

Answer (score 7):

None of solutions worked for me until I edit `runtimeExecutable` with following value:

```
"runtimeExecutable": "${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/nodemon/bin/nodemon.js",
```

Which gives:

```
{
  "name": "debug nodemon",
  "type": "node",
  "request": "launch",
  "runtimeExecutable": "${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/nodemon/bin/nodemon.js",
  "program": "${workspaceFolder}/app.js",
  "restart": true,
  "console": "integratedTerminal",
  "internalConsoleOptions": "neverOpen"
},
```

Answer (score 3):

You can launch and attach nodemon with F5, however it will require a little more setup.

We will have to first pre-launch nodemon via VS Code task and then attach.

I'm using remote debugger to attach since it does not require additional clicks to select the process to attach, and VS Code process picker is currently [broken in WSL2](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/75932), which is my main development environment.

tasks.json (from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54017304/987801)):

```
{
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "tasks": [
    {
      "label": "npm dev",
      "type": "npm",
      "script": "dev",
      "isBackground": true,

      // This task is run before some debug tasks.
      // Problem is, it's a watch script, and since it never exits, VSCode
      // complains. All this is needed so VSCode just lets it run.
      "problemMatcher": [
        {
          "pattern": [
            {
              "regexp": ".",
              "file": 1,
              "location": 2,
              "message": 3
            }
          ],
          "background": {
            "activeOnStart": true,
            "beginsPattern": ".",
            "endsPattern": "."
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

launch.json:

```
{
  "type": "node",
  "request": "attach",
  "name": "Launch & Attach",
  "restart": true,
  "localRoot": "${workspaceRoot}",
  "remoteRoot": "${workspaceRoot}",
  "preLaunchTask": "npm dev"
}
```

And in npm dev script (for node >= 6.9):

```
nodemon --watch src -e js --exec node --inspect .
```

Note - this approach won't work if your process takes more than 10 seconds to start. 
In that case you will have to figure out how to signal VS Code when the pre-launch task has finished. This probably can be achieved by playing with beginsPattern / endPattern regex, though I haven't tried it.

Answer (score 2):

As @the Geek proposes,

1. You should modify launch.json as follows:

   ```
   {
       "version": "0.2.0",
       "configurations": 
     [    
       {
           "type": "node",
           "request": "attach",
           "name": "Attach by Process ID",
           "processId": "${command:PickProcess}"
       }
     ]
   }
   ```
2. Start server "npm run dev" (as you can see, in "request" property, we set to attach. So we have to run the server firstly and then attach the debugger).
3. Click on the left side of vscode in the bug-like icon. On top you will see the small green play icon. Click on the dropdown arrow right of it and select "Attach by process ID".
4. Click on the play icon and then a bar on the bottom of vscode should turn dark orange. Now try making a request. Breakpoints will be hit correctly!

Answer (score 1):

nodemon listens to files changes and re-start the app on **another process**

So your configuration is correct but the debugger never "sees" the breakpoints .

There is no point of running debug mode with nodemon .

That's is a feature you may want to request on VScode(Auto-Restart on code change)

Comment: So what changes do I need to do to run it in debug mode, any changes in package.json or launch.json that would help me to debug?

Comment: Changes to launch.json . Use node as your executable and the debugger will start stop on breakspoints.(like the first member in your launch.jsomn

Comment: use "runtimeExecutable": "node", instead of "runtimeExecutable": "nodemon"?

Comment: sorry didn't work, the app runs but doesn't pause on any of the breakpoints :'(

Answer (score 1):

I was searching for the same problem and encountered this question, as now in 1. July 2022, this seems to be the best way. Using the **Auto-Attach** feature in VSCode.

I followed the article [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/nodejs-debugging#_auto-attach), restarted the IDE, set a breakpoint, and ran my code with:

```
nodemon app.js
```

everything worked correctly as expected.

so Proccess:

```
  Activating Auto Attach -> Restarting IDE -> Setting Break Points-> Running with Nodemon
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a problem with all the proposed answers because my MVSC workspace was not directly the folder containing the package.json file. I therefore add to Ridham Tarpara's answer ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59373131/15460320)).
For it to work with a workspace of this type (my package.json file is inside the directory `server`

[my workspace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9curj.png)

You need to create a .launch.json file in the workspace's .vscode folder.

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "type": "node",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "nodemon",
      "runtimeArgs": ["--prefix", "${workspaceRoot}/server", "run", "debug"],
      "runtimeExecutable": "npm",
      "program": "${workspaceRoot}/server/",
      "restart": true,
      "console": "integratedTerminal",
      "internalConsoleOptions": "neverOpen"
    }
  ]
}
```

The key is to specify to npm where the package.json defining the "debug" command is located using the `--prefix` argument to at the end, launch this kind of command `npm --prefix path/to/dir/containing/npm/package run debug`.

Then here is my package.json running nodemon in full typescript

```
{
  ...
  "scripts": {
    "start": "tsc && nodemon server",
    "debug": "tsc && nodemon --watch 'server/lib/**' --ext 'ts,json' --exec 'ts-node server.ts'",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
...
}
```