# How to inspect a nodemon executed script?

Tags: node.js, debugging, nodemon

I have a script inside a node app that I am running like this:

```
nodemon({
  script: this.settings.serverScriptPath,
  ext: 'ts tsx json',
  verbose: this.debug,
  stdout: false
});
```

I am trying to debug using the `debugger` directive,
[image]

However devtools does not stop there, even if I set the `--inspect-brk` directive

It's possible to inspect and set a `debugger` directive into it? Or to inspect it in any way?

Comment: Have you seen [How to debug a nodemon project in VSCode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53352303/how-to-debug-a-nodemon-project-in-vscode)?

Comment: @Wyck... yes I saw that. But that´s not what I'm looking for.